# Program prints only first three characters in array in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

My program is to read characters into an array and display it to the console. But I don't know why it only reads first 3 characters.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {    
    int length=0,i;
    char str[10];
    cout<<"Enter a string"<<"\n";

    for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        cin>>str[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        cout<<str[i];
        length++;
    }
    cout<<"\n"<<"Length of the string="<<""<<length<<"\n";
}
```

The output looks like:

[image]

Comment: You should learn [how to use a debuger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) ...` in this line `str[i]`, has undefined contents (as you never initialised `str`) you can't test it's value.

Comment: `for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)` -> `for(i=0; i < sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0])-1; i++)`, reading uninitialised data invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: `for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){` which str[i] will contain a ’\0’?

Comment: switch to std::string ... we are living in the c++ world

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings, `-Wall -Wextra` command line switches, and fix any warnings you get.

Comment: Also for C strings that really are terminated `std::cout << my_null_terminated_string;` is enough to print them.

Comment: @RichardCritten are you saying that str[3] = '\0', which happen randomly since it is uninitialised ??

Comment: The declaration of `char str[10];` does not initialise it.  It get whatever values are on the stack at the time the program is run.  Reading from `str[i]` without initialising it is undefined behaviour - it may give you a random value, it may format your computer. See: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html (also applied to C++).

Comment: I call this White Queen code... checking value before setting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR version

```
std::string str; //use std::string. practically no reasons not to in C++
if (cin >> str) // read into string and test that read succeeded.
{
    std::cout << str << '\n'
              << "Length of the string=" << str.length() << endl;
}
```

## Explaining and salvaging Asker's version

```
for(i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){ // str[i] tested here
    cin>>str[i]; // but it has no assigned value until here.
```

uses `str[i]` before it is assigned a value. The program likely found a null character in the block of memory allocated for `str` and stopped prematurely, but technically anything can happen if you use an uninitialized variable. For example, you got the expected result 3 times before finding the null. The program could never found a null and run forever. It could have rained unicorns. Anything.

```
int i = 0;
do {
    cin>>str[i];
} while (str[i++] != '\0');
```

reads then tests. But lines of data in a stream are not C-style strings and are not terminated with null.

```
int i = 0;
do {
    cin>>str[i];
} while (!std::isspace(str[i++]));
```

exits when whitespace is found, typically signalling the end of a word, rather than null.

But what if `cin>>str[i];` failed for some reason?

```
int i = 0;
do {
    cin>>str[i];
} while (cin && !std::isspace(str[i++]));
```

Adds a test to ensure something was read. But what if there are more than 10 characters and `char str[10];` is overflowed?

```
int i = 0;
do {
    cin>>str[i];
} while (cin && !std::isspace(str[i]) && ++i < sizeof(str));
```

unless I am reading That is legal unless I'm reading **[expr.cond]** and **[expr.log.and]** wrong, sequencing of when `++i` occurs in `!std::isspace(str[i]) && ++i < sizeof(str))` is guaranteed to not affect `!std::isspace(str[i])`

But what if you run out of space before find the null? `str` is unterminated and not a string! This ruins the for loop later in the program.

```
int i = 0;
do {
    cin>>str[i];
} while (cin && !std::isspace(str[i]) && ++i < sizeof(str));
if (i == sizeof(str))
{
    str[sizeof(str)-1] = '\0';
}
```

I think that covers everything you're likely to run into here.

Comment: `str[i]` in `while`-test is not initialized. You need to test `str[i-1]`

Comment: @peje You are seeing something that I am not. Please explain.

Comment: @user4581301: `cin>>str[i];i++; } while (...isspace(str[i])` tests a value that has not been written to `str` so far...

Answer (score 4):

**Here are some of the issues I noticed:**

1. You're checking the contents of `str` before you even initialize it.
2. You're assuming the string you're fetching from the stream will be null-terminated, but that's actually not the case.
3. You aren't checking whether cin is working correctly
4. You don't check to make sure the string is 10 characters or less, this could cause you to overflow past the end of the buffer
5. When you're checking the length of the array, again you assume the string is null-terminated

If you want to fix these issues and still use a char buffer, see user4581301's comprehensive answer. However, I'd suggest simply switching to `std::string.` For example:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout<<"Enter a string"<<"\n";
    if (cin >> str) {
        cout << str << endl;
        cout << "Length of the string = " << str.length() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, looks like there are already some good explanations

Comment: Recommend adding the explanation anyway. Answers do get deleted from time to time, and you should strive to be self-contained.

Comment: Okay, I added the stuff I noticed, but I also pointed to your answer since I think it's a great breakdown of how to make it work with a char buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You read in character by character and store it in `str[i]`; but then you increment `i++` before checking `str[i]!='\0'`.

There are two issues with this approach: First, you check a value at a position that has not been written at that point in time. Second, `cin>>str[i]` will never write the string termination character - it just reads in valid characters, and if input is terminated (e.g. by EOF), nothing is written.

So you are approaching this the wrong way.

If you want to read at most 10 characters up to a new line (i.e. when the user presses enter), use `fgets`. Or - and this is the preferred option - use `cin` and write into an `std::string`-object.

```
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    cin >> str;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

str[i] != '\0' checks the pre-existing data stored at str[i], not the user-input value.

Comment: `str` is dereferenced before the check, so a check doesn't actually have to occur.

Comment: Afraid not. No guarantee of a null character being in the stream. streams are not c-style strings.

Answer (score 0):

Add string initialization:

```
char str[10] = {'\0'};
```

and change the reading with:

```
char c;
for(int i = 0; cin>> c && c!=/*add your termination cond. here*/ && i < 10;++i)
    str[i] = c;
```

So you can ensure that the string is filled with correct values and terminated appropriately.

But better solution would be to use **std::string**. In that case you dont have to check the sizes, because the string grows by itself.For example:

```
    std::string str;
    for(char c; cin>>c && c!=/*add your termination cond. here*/;) 
        str += c;
```

Comment: It's not ruining the loop, because the loop checks the inputed character and not the string itself. You are right that it's not maintainer friendly, but that wasn't the question.